# How to pass from lm.fit to optim in R?

Tags: r, optimization, regression

I am using a function to do a linear regression and works fine.:
here it is:

```
fun <- function(x1, x2, y) {
```

but now I have a non-linear equation so I want to use `optim` instead of `lm.fit` in the above `Fun`.

the optim function is here:

```
  f <- function(p){
      sum((y - (p[1]*x1+p[2]*x2+p[3])^p[4]+p[5])^2)
                  }

  p <- optim(rep(.5, 5), f)$par
```

Any idea please on how to implement this function in the first one? and remove `lm.fit`

Comment: You can do a nonlinear least squares fitting with `nls`

Comment: I guess it should be something like `nls(y~((p1*x1+p2*x2+p3)^p4+p5), data.frame(x1,x2,y), start=c(p1=.5,p2=.5,p3=.5,p4=.5,p5=.5))`

Answer (score 1):

If you determined to use `optim`, you can try this approach:

```
make.fun <- function(x1,x2,y,n.keep=3) {
  keep <- !(is.na(x1) | is.na(x2) | is.na(y))
  if (sum(keep)<n.keep) return()
  function(p){
    sum((y - (p[1]*x1+p[2]*x2+p[3])^p[4]+p[5])^2)
  }
}

f <- make.fun(x1,x2,y)
p <- if (is.null(f)) rep(NA,5) else optim(rep(.5,5),f)$par
```

Here, `make.fun` tests if you have enough complete rows and if yes, it returns a function to be minimized. That function will already have `x1`, `x2`, and `y` in its environment, so it will need only `p` as input, which is convenient for use with `optim`.